# How to compare strings in two files?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, compare

I'm newbie in C, any help would be appreciated on this project.I need an expert advice on this project who has tried before similar ones?

I'm going to use C to read two files (contain array of string or just strings and numbers which ever best for the performance) and compare strings in two files line by line (first line in the first file with the first line in the second file, second line in the first file with the second line in the second file...) and printf them if they match or unmatch. I need to find the fastest way to complete this operation (I can also change the file structure if needed). The sample files below;

```
File1:                            File2:

Dens1                             Dens1
Hige0                             Hige1
Alte1                             Alte0
Some1                             Some1
```

I was think about the following options;

```
option1:

fopen
fgets
memcmp/strcmp/strstr
printf

option2:

open
mmap the file
search and pointer the data from mmap
close

option3:

Reading second file completely and store the content in a array. Then read from the first file and compare.

option4:
your opinion?
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution depends to a large degree on the contents of your files. If you know that the files are sorted, reading from both files at the same time, line by line, will work. If your files can be extremely large (relative to available RAM), methods that require reading entire files into memory won't work.

You need to define your problem better to have enough information to decide the best solution.

Comment: This *might* be better suited as a comment to the original question, not as an answer

Answer (score 0):

AdamO, here is it an easy way to achieve what you want.
Good luck in your assignment.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[30], str2[30];
    FILE *fpOne, *fpTwo;
    int x = 0;
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    char ch;

    //Assuming both files has the same number of lines
    fpOne = fopen("FileTextOne.txt","r");
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(fpOne);

        if(ch=='\n')
        {
            numberOfLines++;
        }

    }while(ch != EOF);
    fclose(fpOne);



    fpOne = fopen("FileTextOne.txt","r");
    fpTwo = fopen("FileTextTwo.txt","r");

    do
    {
        fscanf(fpOne,"\n%s", str1);
        fscanf(fpTwo,"\n%s", str2);

        if(strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\t", str1);
            printf("%s\t", str2);
            printf("\t - are identical Strings.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\t", str1);
            printf("%s\t", str2);
            printf("\t - are not identical Strings.\n");
        }

        x++;

    }while(x!=(numberOfLines+1));


    fclose(fpOne);
    fclose(fpTwo);
    return(0);
}
```

#### FileTextOne

Dens1 
Hige0 
Alte1 
Some1 
Dog   
Donkey

#### FileTextTwo

Dens1 
Hige0 
Alte1 
Some1 
Cat   
Donkey

Comment: Thanks for the code. Works like a charm. I was thinking that buffering the second file and compare with the first one was the fastest way to do that so.Thanks anyway.